# Use void Apex method in Lightning Web Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to migrate an Aura component to a Lightning Web Component.

```
@AuraEnabled public static void updateRecords(Id recordId, String newStatus){...}
```

I have a public static void apex method which I am calling, but since it is void, the component javascript doesn't handle the response well.

```
submitResponse(){
    this.showSpinner = true;
    updateRecords({recordId: this.recordId, newStatus: this.newStatus})
    .then(result => {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);
        if (result) { //never true
            this.showToast("Success!", "Success", "error");
            this.showSpinner = false;
        }
        this.showSpinner = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.showToast("Error!", "error", "error");
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    });

}
```

What are the best practices for using void return type on Apex methods which are called from a lightning web component?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike LC (Aura), the parameters sent back are different. If you reach the ".then", the call was successful, otherwise there was an error. There's no need for you to check if the result was successful.

```
submitResponse(){
    this.showSpinner = true;
    updateRecords({recordId: this.recordId, newStatus: this.newStatus})
    .then(() => {
        this.showToast("Success!", "Success", "No error!");
        this.showSpinner = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.showToast("Error!", "error", "error");
        this.error = error;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    });
}
```